# Right Google Cloud Product

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, bigdata, cloud

Your globally distributed auction application allows users to bid on items. Occasionally, users place identical bids at nearly identical times, and different application servers process those bids. Each bid event contains the item, amount , user, and timestamp. You want to collate those bid events into a single location in real time to determine which user bid first. What should you do?(choose one)

(A) Create a file on a shared file and have the application servers write all bid events to that file. Process the file with Apache Hadoop to identify which user bid first.

(B) Have each application server write the bid events to Cloud Pub/Sub as they occur. Push the events from Cloud Pub/Sub to a custom endpoint that writes the bid event information into Cloud SQL.

(C) Set up a MySQL database for each application server to write bid events into. Periodically query each of those distributed MySQL databases and update a master MySQL database with bid event information.

(D) Have each application server write the bid events to Google Cloud Pub/Sub as they occur. Use a pull subscription to pull the bid events using Google Cloud Dataflow. Give the bid for each item to the user in the bid event that is processed first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I choose (D). Here are the following reasons:

- Cloud Pub/Sub is a managed service and message-oriented middleware, in other words, it delivers messages.

  > "users place identical bids at nearly identical times, and different application servers process those bids."

  With Pub/Sub you would just need to config publishers [1](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview#concepts) from the end users, it will send the bids to the topic and later on you can process these data. So I will eliminate (A)(C) first, you don't want to manage you own Hadoop or MySQL server if you have a better option and that is **Cloud Pub/Sub**.
- There is another key sentence

  > "collate those bid events into a single location in real time."

  **Cloud Dataflow(Apache Beam)** [2](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/) supports both streaming and batch processing. There is a function called **Triggers**, you can trigger by data's event time also same as the time that the user bid on.
- You don't want to store these real time data into Cloud SQL [3](https://cloud.google.com/sql/).

Comment: I think that's correct.

Comment: @Mahesh Thanks, would you mark my comment as the correct answer, so people will know.